# jQuery $.ajax call fails for getting JSON using YouTube API in some videos

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I'm trying to get, among other details, the title of a given video for a certain YouTube video. Because they're all probably rooted in the same problem, I'll just show a simplified example with just getting the title using the API. Here's what I have so far:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID + "?v=2&alt=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        videoName = data.entry.title.$t;
        $('#video_name').text(videoName);
    }
});
```

For some videos, such as [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJMPK5DLEXk), this works perfectly. For others, such as [this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oSd0keSj2W8), it doesn't grab that information ever.

Why does this not work? That second example is just one video that does not work with this. About 1/3 don't work it seems.

I'd really appreciate some insight on this.

**EDIT** How I'm getting `videoID`:

```
var videoID = getUrlVars()["v"];
function getUrlVars() {
    var vars = {};
    var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi, 
    function(m,key,value) {
        vars[key] = value;
    });
    return vars;
}
```

The example video ends like so: `?v=J66NOwZegc4`

**EDIT2** So I've added the $.ajax function with what seems to be causing the problem instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/" + videoID + "?v=2&alt=json",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    async: "false",
    success: function(data) {
        commentCount = data.entry.gd$comments.gd$feedLink.countHint;
        iterations = Math.floor(commentCount/50);
        remaining = commentCount - (iterations*50);
        videoDesc = data.entry.title.$t;
        $('#video_name').text(videoDesc);
        document.title = 'Watching "' + videoDesc + '" on YTRT';
        $('#shareLink').val('http://www.ytrealtime.com?v=' + videoID);
    }
});
```

Comment: works fine here for the 2 you provided  http://jsfiddle.net/9e2TP/  Show other code that passes `videoID` to `$.ajax`

Comment: works perfectly as well http://jsfiddle.net/9e2TP/1/

Comment: @VirendraRajput just realized that. If you look at my 2nd edit, you'll see what I've found. For whatever reason, that second example doesn't have that `data.entry.gd$comments.gd$feedLink.countHint` to show the number of comments.

Comment: you will have to check the API, see what is optional in response, and test if it exists or not. API should give you a full breakdown of response schema

Comment: The only thing I can find is talking about the `feedLink`, but even that doesn't exist in this response.