# cast_sender.js error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED in Chrome

Tags: javascript, youtube

I recently started receiving the following console errors, without any code changes taking place.

I did not install any extensions recently.

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
```

I have several YouTube player embeds on the page that are triggering this error, but they are simple:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/OUR_YOUTUBE_ID?showinfo=0&amp;wmode=transparent" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
```

Has anybody else experienced this?

Comment: I'm hitting this too.  Is it causing your JS not to run on the page?

Comment: Infrequently, yes. I was able to replicate it a few times where it would break JS on the page, but most times I just see the console errors.

Comment: Is the embedded video still loading for you? It's not for me, which is bad.

Comment: amazingly, google adwords support is blocking sites that have this issue. highly frustrating.

Comment: This is fixed in Chrome 49 per @Paul Irish. https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=538#hc18

Comment: To stop seeing those cast_sender.js errors, edit the youtube link in the iframe src and change embed to v

Comment: Not fixed as of now, using latest Chrome on Mac - 49.0.2623.112 (64-bit).

Comment: After updating from Chrome 48 to 49 on Windows, there are less of these errors in the console for me than before, but they still appear.

Comment: Try disabling Adblocker extension for the site. Worked for me.

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Apparently YouTube constantly polls for Google Cast scripts even if the extension isn't installed.

From one [**commenter**](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=309#c28):

> ... it appears that Chrome attempts to get cast_sender.js on pages that have YouTube content. I'm guessing when Chrome sees media that it can stream it attempts to access the Chromecast extension. When the extension isn't present, the error is thrown.

[**Read more**](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=309)

The only solution I've come across is to install the [**Google Cast**](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd) extension, whether you need it or not. You may then hide the toolbar button.

For more information and updates, see **[this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26095117/1264804)**. Here's the [**official issue**](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=309).

Answer (score 41):

I'm going to add to the [answer given before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27448688/1346510).

It's not a bug in your code or the browser's code. It's the JavaScript code **inside** the YouTube iframe polls for the extensions it could interoperate with in case they were installed (likely to determine if the extension is installed).

Look at the source of `www-embed-player.js` (loaded from `s.ytimg.com`, it's YouTube static files CDN).
You'll find the following:

```
function Wj(a){return"chrome-extension://"+a+"/cast_sender.js"}
```

Comment: What do you suggest then? I **don't** want to install the Google Cast extension ! Something like overriding this function?

Comment: I can't find it in the source: https://s.ytimg.com/yts/jsbin/www-widgetapi-vfllgPgCl/www-widgetapi.js

Comment: First of all: overriding that function should not work, and you should not want to override functions of other people's sites. If you do succeed in doing that, you've succeeded in hacking Google Chrome, YouTube, or both. Also, it's their bug, not yours. Just file a bug report or something.Second, @sompylasar mentions that the code is in the source of a file called `www-embed-player.js`. Can you explain to us why you are looking at a different file but expect that function to be in there nevertheless?

Answer (score 22):

To stop seeing those cast_sender.js errors, edit the youtube link in the iframe src and change `embed` to `v`

Comment: This worked for me, though I will add that you should only do this for Chrome, because in Firefox, this will cause the video to be loaded as Flash and will show a blocked plugin message.

Comment: Requiring a user to have flash installed in firefox, while annoying, is probably a better option than the Javascript on your webpage breaking. On my site, this issue seems to have a flow on affect preventing the required FontAwesome font from being downloaded. We will use this solution for now until we can re-work the way we embed videos on our site.

Comment: if you change the embed to v, then my iframe will not work. Any advice? i used this solution from this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/8521287/4812515

Comment: Keep in mind .../v/... is depricated https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#Selecting_Content_to_Play

Comment: Bad idea. If you use v instead of embed, youtube will use flash player instead of native html player.

Answer (score 2):

The error is try to fix a Youtube error.

The solution to avoid your Javascript-Console-Error complex is to accept that Youtube (and also other webpages) can have Javascript errors that you can't fix.

That is all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix for this is to install the [Google Cast](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-cast/boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd?utm_source=yourmom) extension. If you don't have a Chromecast, or don't want to use the extension, no problem; just don't use the extension.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what was already said - in order to avoid this error from interfering (stopping) other Javascript code on your page, you could try forcing the YouTube iframe to load last - after all other Javascript code is loaded.