# Youtube IFrame API Untrusted Origin

Tags: javascript, iframe, youtube

I'm using the IFrame API as the title suggests. I have been following the guide in the [API Reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference). It works for me however I have found a few warnings that occur and would like to solve them. They are:

> Untrusted origin: https://www.youtube.com

and

> Untrusted origin: chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd

both of which originate from www-embed-player.js:331

Through my research I have found that the second one happens because it [constantly polls for the chromecast extension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27448688/4330669) (kinda weird but its google). If I disable the chromecast extension that warning becomes errors such as:

> GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILED

from www-embed-player.js:163

I have tried adding the [enablejsapi and origin](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?playerVersion=HTML5#origin) parameters mentioned with no change in luck.

I have also tried adding the IFrame directly as mentioned in [Loading a Video Player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Loading_a_Video_Player) which didn't remove the untrusted origin errors, and also broke my javascript functionality.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error has been acknowledged by Google:

https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=309

> This is per design; in order to know if a user has the Chromecast
>   extension installed (and which one), cast_sender.js requests the
>   script from all potentially installed extensions.

This question has also been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/26095117/1007392

Best, 
Sam

Comment: Note that even if you have the chromecast extension loaded you still get warning messages.