# Chrome error when embedding video url with iframe

Tags: google-chrome, iframe, browser, google-chrome-extension

When I embed some url into page with iframe I'm getting the following error's in chrome console. Why is this happening?

```
GET chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILEDfj @ www-embed-player-new.js:151ej @ www-embed-player-new.js:151dj @ www-embed-player-new.js:151ij @ www-embed-player-new.js:152gl @ www-embed-player-new.js:205so @ www-embed-player-new.js:301Dq @ www-embed-player-new.js:340(anonymous function) @ FQpUOimNvXA?showinfo=0:10
    www-embed-player-new.js:22

GET https://static.doubleclick.net/instream/ad_status.js net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENTlc @ www-embed-player-new.js:22ic @ www-embed-player-new.js:21fc @ www-embed-player-new.js:21xd @ www-embed-player-new.js:35Dq @ www-embed-player-new.js:341(anonymous function) @ FQpUOimNvXA?showinfo=0:10
    www-embed-player-new.js:151

GET chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILEDfj @ www-embed-player-new.js:151ej @ www-embed-player-new.js:151(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player-new.js:151c.onerror @ www-embed-player-new.js:151
    www-embed-player-new.js:151

GET chrome-extension://hfaagokkkhdbgiakmmlclaapfelnkoah/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILEDfj @ www-embed-player-new.js:151ej @ www-embed-player-new.js:151(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player-new.js:151c.onerror @ www-embed-player-new.js:151
    www-embed-player-new.js:151

GET chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILEDfj @ www-embed-player-new.js:151ej @ www-embed-player-new.js:151(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player-new.js:151c.onerror @ www-embed-player-new.js:151
    www-embed-player-new.js:151 

GET chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILEDfj @ www-embed-player-new.js:151ej @ www-embed-player-new.js:151(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player-new.js:151c.onerror @ www-embed-player-new.js:151
    www-embed-player-new.js:151

GET chrome-extension://eojlgccfgnjlphjnlopmadngcgmmdgpk/cast_sender.js net::ERR_FAILEDfj @ www-embed-player-new.js:151ej @ www-embed-player-new.js:151(anonymous function) @ www-embed-player-new.js:151c.onerror @ www-embed-player-new.js:151
```

Comment: Its bug in Chrome if the Chrome Cast Extension is not Installed . [Check Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490323/google-chrome-cast-sender-error-if-chrome-cast-extension-is-not-installed-or-usi)

Comment: @sudhAnsu63 yeap, seems true, thanks for replying

Comment: I wouldn't call it a bug..

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Chrome Cast. Why in the world is this marked as a duplicate? Do we have a few overly-hasty admins?...

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Seems Like an AdBlocker extension in enabled. you can see the same types of errors on the YouTube page itself. These Extensions block certain Web-requests if they match some sort of ad related URI.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks!

Comment: your welcome.. Glad I could help.

Comment: In my case it was the PrivacyBadger extension. Really appreciate the answer that helped me to narrow it down quickly.