# Youtube: this.f.isExternalMethodAvailable is not a function

Tags: javascript, youtube

I am getting the following error in console shortly after my website loads:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this.f.isExternalMethodAvailable is not a function
```

~ Error from file: `www-embed-player.js, line number: 669`

Which is occurring inside the iframe generated by Youtube so I can't do much about it but wanted to know if this error can be fixed from my end.

I am using following JS code to inject youtube iframe tag in multiple places in DOM

```
$(this).append('<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + youtubeVideoID + '?&controls=0&enablejsapi=1&mute=1&theme=dark&autoplay=' + autoPlay + '&autohide=1&modestbranding=0&fs=0&playlist=' + youtubeVideoID + '&showinfo=0&rel=0&iv_load_policy=3&loop=1&playsinline=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
$(this).parent().find('iframe')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');

$(this).parent().find('iframe').eq(0).on('load', function () {
    this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"playVideo","args":""}', '*');
});
```

Comment: Might be caused by AdBlocker, as here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32626135/chrome-error-when-embedding-video-url-with-iframe . Also what browser is used?

Comment: @Renat I did checked, that is not the case for me.

Comment: Did you solve your problem? @ImranBughio

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Answer (score 2):

For anyone finding this via google - I started receiving this error when I enabled the new [Permissions-Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Feature-Policy) security header on my web site.

Specifically, if the header value contained either of these:

"`usb=()`" or "`payment=()`" then the issue appears.

So, removing them seems to have fixed the issue for me.