# How to detect if Google Cast extension is installed in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, chromecast, google-cast

I am developing a Google Cast sender application and on my web page in chrome browser, I need to detect if the Google Cast extension is installed or not before doing something.

I did some searching and found some suggestions for detecting chrome extensions if developer owns both website and extension. In my case, I am trying to detect an extension not developed by me. Is there an API or another way to detect installation of a third party chrome extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way (used by the library itself) of detecting whether the extension is installed is to try and load a web-accessible file from it.

This, however, leads to [an unwanted effect of producing error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490323/google-chrome-cast-sender-error-if-chrome-cast-extension-is-not-installed-or-usi) in the console (which are "network" errors and not JS errors, and therefore cannot be hidden) when Cast is *not* installed.

Also, you should not do this probing yourself, specifically because you don't control Google Cast - and it's not guaranteed to be stable in how it operates internally. There is a library you're expected to use as a Sender, and you should rely on the [library initialization callback](https://developers.google.com/cast/v2/chrome_sender#Initialization) for detecting Cast.

Comment: Valid point regarding letting the Cast library do the detection and I changed my code to do so.