# Trying to detect google chrome cast and stop it slowing things down

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, youtube

```
window.onerror=function(err,url,line){
    if(err=='boom'){
        console.log(true);
        }
    else{
        console.log(false);
        }};

console.error('boom');
```

This outputs `undefined`!

How can I tell in the java-script what text the error contains?

I'm trying to detect google chrome cast extension error

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE chrome-extension://boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd/cast_sender.js

related: [Google chrome cast sender error if chrome cast extension is not installed or using incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490323/google-chrome-cast-sender-error-if-chrome-cast-extension-is-not-installed-or-usi)

My reasoning is

```
//​tried to detect chromecast extension id: boadgeojelhgndaghljhdicfkmllpafd
//it looks like it is protected from detection (tried: http://blog.kotowicz.net/2012/02/intro-to-chrome-addons-hacking.html)
//if they are using:
//chrome flash           ===flash     (needs double click as &autoplay=1 lets the user do only one click but it side-effects with no video preview)
//chrome       chromeCast===fastjs    (google are being bad players here!)
//chrome                 ===slowjs   (almost unusable website)
//chrome flash chromeCast===flash    ffsake! (maybe try one video then see if there are errors and put a cookie, chromecast=true means that we got no errors so we don't need flash!) todo:how to analyse error text?
//if the user is on chrome and does not have flash then they are youtubes 'exception'! they will have very crap loading times


var chrome=0;
if(/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&/Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor)){
    chrome=1;
    function detectPlugin(substrs){
        if(navigator.plugins){
            for(var i=0,l=navigator.plugins.length;i<l;i++){
                var plugin=navigator.plugins[i]
                ,   haystack=plugin.name+plugin.description
                ,   found=0;
                for(var j=0;j<substrs.length;j++){
                    if(haystack.indexOf(substrs[j])!=-1){found++;}
                    }
                if(found==substrs.length){return true;}
                }}
            return false;
            }
        var detectFlash=[/*"Shockwave",*/"Flash"]; //not entirely sure how relevant shockwave is here
        if(detectPlugin(detectFlash)){chrome=2;}
        }
```

then I create an iframe with:

```
'https://www.youtube.com/'+(chrome==2?'v':'embed')+'/'+ytvidcode
```

where `ytvidcode` is the id of the youtube video

`v` is for the depreciated flash embed while `embed` is for the html5 (broken/[wont fix](https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=309)) embed

So the above code will detect chrome then will attempt to detect flash but cannot detect chrome-cast.

If the user has both chrome-cast and flash then (as it cannot detect chrome-cast/chrome-cast errors) it will force flash if present.

If flash is not present then the user will have a crappy youtube embed experience (they might have to use another browser)

**Is it possible to detect the errors made by chrome-cast or any other footprint of its presence?**

because if it is an installed extension then it should be fully utilized as flash is depreciated

---

```
window.onerror=function(e,url,line){console.dir(arguments);}//nope

window.onerror=function(e,url,line){console.dir(this);}//nope
```

---

https://github.com/Valve/fingerprintjs2

```
new Fingerprint2().get(function(result, components){
    console.log(result); //a hash, representing your device fingerprint
    console.log(components); // an array of FP components
    });
```

`components[13]` ("regular_plugins") shows no Google cast even though I have installed it today

---

The only thing I can think of at this point is to time the loading of one of their videos (if they are on chome and it takes too long to load the test video then they must not have chrome cast), using this https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started and a timer and a cookie after (so the test only happens once)... *I will test this then perhaps report back*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lets the videos use `embed` if non chrome or if they are on chrome with cast extension enabled.

If they are on chrome without cast then it checks for flash and if they support flash then it uses `v`.

If they have chrome without ether cast or flash then (they will just get the chrome cast errors, it's their fault at that point!)

> `v` is for the depreciated flash embed while `embed` is for the html5 (broken/wont fix) embed.

Could do with improvements maybe...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.gstatic.com/cv/js/sender/v1/cast_sender.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function proceed(how){
                document.getElementById('vid').innerHTML='<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/'+how+'/M_lHI1opADk"></iframe>';
                console.log(ischrome,iscast);
                }
            var ytv=['embed','v','embed','v'];
            var ischrome=0;
            var iscast=true;//maybe
            if(/Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&/Google Inc/.test(navigator.vendor)){
                ischrome=1;
                setTimeout(function(){
                    try{new chrome.cast.SessionRequest('794B7BBF');}
                    catch(e){console.log(e);
                        iscast=false;}
                    finally{
                        (iscast==true)&&(ischrome=2);
                        if(ischrome==1){
                            function hasflash(){if(navigator.plugins){for(var i=0,l=navigator.plugins.length;i<l;i++){if((navigator.plugins[i].name+navigator.plugins[i].description).indexOf("Flash")!=-1){return true;}}}return false;}
                            if(hasflash()){ischrome=3;}
                            proceed(ytv[ischrome]);
                            }
                        else{
                            proceed(ytv[ischrome]);
                            }}},1000);}
            else{proceed(ytv[ischrome]);}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="vid"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can test this by installing the cast extension disabling/enabling and refreshing the page.

Comment: Don't forget to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.