# Moodle: Javascript errors preventing SCORM package loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, moodle

I'm new here and having some issues on my Moodle site through which I provide online training.  We upload SCORM packages to the Moodle and recently have had an issue which is stopping the SCORM packages from loading or sometimes just taking a very long time to load.

We receive the SCORM error that the "SCORM player has determined that your internet connection is unreliable or has been interrupted.  If you continue in the SCORM activity, your progress may not be saved.  You should exit the activity now and return when you have a dependable connection".

However, we have tried this from a number of different internet points and devices, with the same problem reoccurring.  We therefore contacted our hosting provider, who replied:

"It appears the issue is coming from the fact that there are quite a few JavaScript errors on the site. I am pasting them below:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> chrome-extension://dliochdbjfkdbacpmhlcpmleaejidimm/cast_sender.js
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> chrome-extension://enhhojjnijigcajfphajepfemndkmdlo/cast_sender.js
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> chrome-extension://fmfcbgogabcbclcofgocippekhfcmgfj/cast_sender.js
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> chrome-extension://pkedcjkdefgpdelpbcmbmeomcjbeemfm/cast_sender.js
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED
>
> chrome-extension://fjhoaacokmgbjemoflkofnenfaiekifl/cast_sender.js
>
> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED 4jquery.js:5 Uncaught
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of null(anonymous
> function)
>
> @ jquery.js:5x.extend.access
>
> @ jquery.js:3x.fn.(anonymous function)
>
> @ jquery.js:5e @ content-script.js:1d
>
> @ content-script.js:1(anonymous function)
>
> @ content-script.js:1"

Can anyone assist and help me identify what the problem is that is causing the loading issues with my SCORM packages?

Kind regards

Eddie

Comment: Hello! I put an answer, please, tell us if it's valid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the message `SCORM player has determined that your internet connection is unreliable or has been interrupted` on all moodle servers, but the server is working fine and the work is saved correctly.

My solutions are two:

1. Set a bigger timeout (by default, moodle check internet connection with a 2 seconds timeout). You can set this parameter in 5, 7 or 10 seconds. You can set this value on `lib/yui/src/checknet/js/checknet.js` (search the request to a `checknet.txt` file)
2. Remove the checknet functionality. You can comment two lines on `/mod/scorm/player.php`. The lines you need to comment are these:

   ```
    $PAGE->requires->string_for_js('networkdropped', 'mod_scorm');
    $PAGE->requires->yui_module('moodle-core-checknet', 'M.core.checknet.init', array(array(
        'message' => array('networkdropped', 'mod_scorm'),
    )));
   ```

This is not a solution for a server that works wrong, this is a solution for a server that works fine but the time of the AJAX response is more than 2 seconds.

Comment: Hi Marcos, 

Unfortunately that still hasn't helped resolve the issue.  Do you have any other suggestions?  I'm wondering whether it might be a hosting issue, but do you think there is anything in the javascript faults the hosting provider said I should look at?

Any suggestion how I can fix those?  Sorry, I'm not a tech person.

Comment: That javascript errors doesn't have any relation with the problem on the server. The problem what is? The solution I tell you solves the problem of appears the message "SCORM player has determined that your internet connection is unreliable or has been interrupted.". If after my solution this message still appears, you are doing something wrong. If the problem is that your hosting is bad, change your company. Try https://esquio.net (best low cost hosting solutions). Talk with him, they suggest you depending on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that the first few (for `cast_sender.js`) are related to the issue at hand; `cast_sender.js` is a local script related to Chrome's ability to use Chromecast functionality.  (Edit: The Google Cast SDK uses a rather "agricultural" method to detect if you're running Chrome with the appropriate extension; it's a known issue. [Google chrome cast sender error if chrome cast extension is not installed or using incognito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24490323/google-chrome-cast-sender-error-if-chrome-cast-extension-is-not-installed-or-usi), https://code.google.com/p/google-cast-sdk/issues/detail?id=309)

The later lines they've pasted seem to bubble up from effectively a null pointer in whatever `content_script.js` is. Is the SCORM content locally produced?  Do you know what software was used to create it - e.g. Articulate or Storyline?  I presume that `content_script.js` is part of the player software?